# Clean 2 Dimentional Array in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, arrays

I declared my multidimentional array like this:

```
Dim invoice_discountitems(100, 1) As String
```

I Fill my array with this:

```
'Fill Array with items discounts
                        For i As Int16 = 0 To data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows.Count - 1
                            invoice_discountitems(i, 0) = data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows(i).Item("item_code")
                            invoice_discountitems(i, 1) = data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows(i).Item("discountitem_average")
                        Next
```

Now how i can remove the filled items of this array? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an array is statically sized, an empty array is the same as a freshly initialized array. So, if you want to clear the whole thing:

```
invoice_discountitems = New String(100, 1)
```

Or, if you wish [to clear specific elements, use Array.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx)

```
Array.Clear(invoice_discountitems, 1, 10)
```